# How to test sending an email in symfony 4 and Swiftmailer

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, swiftmailer, symfony4

this may look stupid but I am wondering how to test the function that sends an email from Gmail, NOT from command line because that thing works fine. I want how to call the function that sends an emails . I have followed this [tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html) .
My **config/packages/imap.yaml** is

```
imap:
    connections:
        example_connection:
            mailbox: "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX"
            username: "kadrad26666@gmail.com"
            password: "password"

        another_connection:
            mailbox: "{localhost:143}INBOX"
            username: "username"
            password: "password"
            attachments_dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/imap/attachments"
            server_encoding: "UTF-8"
```

My **Index function** in  **IndexController** is

```
public function index($name, \Swift_Mailer $mailer) {
    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
        ->setFrom('kadrad26666@gmail.com')
        ->setTo('kadrad26666@gmail.com')
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                // templates/emails/registration.html.twig
                'emails/registration.html.twig',
                array('name' => $name)
            ),
            'text/html'
        )
    ;

    $mailer->send($message);

    return $this->render('registration.html.twig'); }
```

my **twig** is as follows

```
 <div class="box box-solid alert-block">
  <div class="box-header">
    <h3 class="box-title"></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body">
   {{render( controller('App\\Controller\\IndexController::index("hello")') ) }} 
  </div>
</div>
```

It is exactly in `index($name, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)` that I am stuck , what parameters should I give.

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think this is the most efficient approach** in doing this. Including template fragments works in some cases but I doubt whether this is the correct approach for this particular scenario.

But, if you really want to do this, you can create an `Swift_Mailer` object and pass on to the `twig` as a parameter,

```
// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

// Create a message
$message = (new Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
  ->setFrom(['john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'])
  ->setTo(['receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'])
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ;

// Pass the $mailer to the twig as a parameter.
```

More :- https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/messages.html

What I would do is create a controller function which calls a services function to send the email and embed that controller call to the twig (Like you are already doing). In that Controller function you do not want to accept parameters. Let the auto-wiring handle the arguments needs for services.

Cheers.

Comment: thanks for your help , but I still dont understand where the `$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);`  line should go. Should it go inside the   `public function index($name, \Swift_Mailer $mailer) { `  function

Comment: It should go inside the function where you call the `twig` file.

Comment: I did exactly so , I added the mailer variable to the **twig**  using    `return $this->renderView('Block/block_alert.html.twig' , array('mailer' => $mailer)); ` and called it as follows     `{{render( controller('App\\Controller\\IndexController::index("hello" , ' ~  mailer ~ ' )') ) }}`  , I know, this should be in another question but I am getting an error message **Variable "mailer" does not exist.** even if I use a string in the array which means that the variable does not get passed to the twig template

Comment: Shouldn't it be like this? `{{render( controller('App\\Controller\\IndexController::index("hello" , mailer)') ) }}` . Without the quotes and stuffs?

Comment: I tried to concatenate the variable , but with your suggestion I get the error message **An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The controller for URI "/_fragment" is not callable. Expected method "index("hello" , mailer )" on class "App\Controller\IndexController". Available methods: "indexAction", "index", "setContainer", "getSubscribedServices".").**

Comment: which is the same error that I get when using any other string other then `mailer`

Comment: Apologies. What you have done earlier was right. That's really really strange. I will have another look when I get chance...

Comment: have a look and let me know , thanks for the help anyway